# Will lighter wheels soften the ride of an Acura RDX?

Tags: wheels, suspension, acura

I've spent some time in a 2016 Acura RDX and I find its ride to be very harsh – every little imperfection in the road is transmitted and felt by the occupants.

The RDX is marketed as a "sporty" SUV, so this may have been by design, but I was looking for aftermarket components that would soften the ride and there appear to be none.

The vehicle I drove has the OEM tires which are 235/60R18, so there's not room to add significant sidewall.  But the wheels are *heavy*!

**Should reducing the ratio of unsprung/sprung weight materially soften the ride?**

Suppose the current wheels+tires are 45 pounds per corner, and I replace them with wheels that are 15 pounds lighter.

Comment: Does the manual, or even the tire pressure sticker in the car, show 17” or even 16” wheels? That may give you a bit more comfort with a sidewall able to flex.

Comment: My "thinking" is, the weight of the wheel will not make a difference in ride quality. The main thing, other than suspension change, which will change your ride is to get a taller sidewall (bigger aspect ratio with smaller diameter rim) as Solar Mike is talking about. While this will improve ride quality, it will also depreciate your handling abilities.